# What's the difference between gwt Activity and Presenter?

Tags: gwt, mvp

From the official tutorial, http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html , the Activity plays the role of a presenter. However, I saw some projects separate the Presenter out of the Activity. Is this the new trend that accepted by most people? Personally, I think it's enough to just use an Activity to handle the view switches and logic parts (just like the Presenter does). Why we need additional Presenter class?

Comment: When you write such a presenter, it's not bound to the GWT dependencies, infrastructure, etc. What's the advantage? You can share the presenter code in different systems like GWT, Android, JavaFX, or even a command-line application still having the same presenter business logic behind it. Additionally, platform-unrelated presenters are much easier to unit-test.